# Agrupar arrays com mesmo valor de índice

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [projeto_id] => 5
            [etapa_num] => 1
            [tarefa] => teste 1 
            [status] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [projeto_id] => 5
            [etapa_num] => 1
            [tarefa] => teste 2
            [status] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [projeto_id] => 5
            [etapa_num] => 2
            [tarefa] => teste 3
            [status] => 0
        )

)
```

Como posso agrupar os arrays que tiverem o mesmo valor de índice? por exemplo:
no código acima os arrays que tiverem o valor do índice **etapa_num = 1**, seriam agrupados em um "array pai".

Comment: Você quer, em resumo, que sejam ordenados pela `key` `etapa_num`?

Comment: Isso, que eles fiquem agrupos num "array pai", que iria agrupar estes dois arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta agrupá-los verificando num laço:

```
$etapas = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $etapas[$value['etapa_num']][] = $value;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/wYLi0C)